# Theoretical question about Fourier Series, I'm confused!

Tags: integration, fourier-series

If I have a function f(x) defined on $[0,L)$, said to be periodic of period $L$ and such that $f(0)\neq0$, how should I get the Fourier coefficients?
I'm hesitating between taking the even extension and integrating over $(-L/2,L/2)$ or same but integrating over $(-L,L)$ or even just integrating without taking the even extension.

Can you tell me? And maybe also tell me why if there is a real reason.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, I ended up typing a wrong question... I'll edit

Comment: For example, how would you find the Fourier Series of f(x) defined as being exp(x) on $[0,\pi)$ and said to have period $\pi$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to integrate over one period, no matter where the limits are. So you could integrate over $[a,a+L)$ with any arbitrary $a$. Sometimes the integration can be simplified by choosing the limits in a clever way, but in principle the only important thing is to integrate over one full period. Continuity and function values do not matter.

Comment: Ok, thank you! That answers perfectly

Comment: @Kika: You're welcome. Please accept the answer so people know that your problem has been solved (by clicking the checkmark next to the question).

Comment: Will do, just a question : if I decide to integrate from -L/2 to L/2, then I should change f(x) to f(x+ L/2) in the part -L/2 to 0, right?

Comment: @Kika: In the interval $[-L/2,0]$ the function has the same values as in $[L/2,L]$, because it's periodic with period $L$. So in $[-L/2,0]$ you need to use $f(x+L)$.

Comment: Oh, yes, that's what I meant, sorry ^^ I'll close the question now, thanks!